# Using session in custom middleware in laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I've simple middleware which checks if there is a key in user session.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CustomAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->session()->has('uid')){
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return view('unauth');
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I always get "Session store not set on request." error. Here is my route:

```
Route::get('home', function () {
        return view('home');
    })->middleware('web', 'CustomAuth');
```

I've added the middleware in app\Http\Kernel.php in the variable $middleware

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CustomAuth::class
    ];
```

I also tried changing my route to this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('home', function () {
        return view('home');
    })->middleware('CustomAuth');
});
```

But this didn't work. Any idea how I can make sure that the session had started, or start it before the middleware is called? I'm using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Move your middleware in the `web` middleware group and after the `SessionStart` middleware.

Comment: Although this is working, it's attaching it to all requests, I managed to i

Comment: The way you had it set up before it was also attached to all requests so I thought that's what you needed. If you don't want that then declare it in the `$routeMiddleware` by name and use it normally (in that case the web middleware would have already ran)

Comment: Thank you, mind giving this as answer so that I can mark it as "Best answer"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The L5 middleware consists of 3 "types".

The configuration is found in the `Kernel.php` file for HTTP requests (typically `App\Http\Kernel`. There's global middleware which will run for all requests and is declared in `$middleware`, there's the route group middleware which will run for all requests for a given route group and is declared in `$middlewareGroups`, by default all routes declared in `web.php` are considered to be `web` routes so all the web middleware apply.

The 3rd type is route middleware. These are declared in the `$routeMiddleware` array in the form `"middlewareName" => Middleware::class` and can be used in any route e.g.

```
Route::get("/route", function () { /* route body */ })->middleware("middlewareName");
```

These run in order global > group > route middleware and the `SessionStart` middleware runs as part of the group middleware. Any other middleware that needs access to the session will need to be placed after the `SessionStart` middleware.

**Clarification**

It occurs to be when re-reading this that this implies that you need to declare the middleware in the `$middeware` variable to use them. This is not the case, the following syntax is also allowed:

```
Route::get("/route", function () { 
   /* route body */ 
})->middleware(Middleware::class);
```

However this syntax will not allow you to provide parameters to the middleware when you use them as you would for example with the authentication middleware when you do `auth:api` (where `api` would be a parameter passed to the middleware).

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos. You saved me.