# Detecting unauthenticated ajax requests in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to handle ajax request that were initiated from idle/expired session(maybe the page was left open and the session got expired). I wrote the below middleware but it's not working as expected:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AjaxSessionCheck
{
/**
* Handle an incoming request.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @param  \Closure  $next
* @return mixed
*/
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!\Auth::check())
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return response()->json(['Session_error'=>'Session Expired'], 401);
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

I also tried to add this code to the Auth middleware with no luck.
**Strangely** enough authenticated(user logged in) ajax requests are detected by this.

Lost 2 days finding solutions. Desperate call here.

Answer (score 0):

use optimised code for performance use both auth::check and request->ajax() in same if condition by AND operator. just try session expiry in configuration file

Answer (score 0):

It's because session runs after middleware, you can see the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652548/using-session-in-custom-middleware-in-laravel#answer-42654024) here. If you want to check that session expired, I think you should use after middleware instead of before middleware

Comment: tried after middleware. No luck. It's not even hitting this part of the code when request comes from invalid session. Dont know where to look.

Comment: did you declare your middleware in kernel.php file?

Comment: yes I did. I can tell it works when the session is valid. Like it detects the ajax request coming from a valid session. But for invalid session, no luck. I am guessing the authentication system detects its invalid session so maybe not letting the request to pass through..I dont know. Its so frustrating!!

Comment: Middleware is used for redirecting user when they are not allowed to go to some page. But if you `return response()`, it cannot show any page. Btw, I haven't tried `$request->ajax()` yet, but I think the problem is there, I tried in my code, and it cannot `return response()`. I `var_dump()` it and it returns false.

Comment: Appreciate your effort to help. Thank you. Will get back if i have something.